# Zeppelin image display with base64 encoded content instead of HTML conversion

Tags: apache-zeppelin

I'm currently working on some visualizations with Zeppelin and Seaborn, but the display mechanism automatically converts images to HTML and this is eating all my RAM immediately. (Too many data points).

Jupyter on the other hand handles it fairly easily, it looks like it just encodes the image content in a Base64 string.

Is it possible to mimic this behavior in Zeppelin? Or, better yet, configure it as the default image handling mechanism?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't know if I can override the default behavior, but this can be achieved manually with html magic. For example:

```
def show(graphics):
    graphics.savefig("../tmp.png")
    with open("../tmp.png", "rb") as image_file:
        encoded_string = base64.b64encode(image_file.read())
    return """%html <img src="data:image/png;base64,{}" />""".format(encoded_string.decode())
```

Returning the html string with base64 encoded png is much more efficient with my data, and I'll probably use this everywhere.